# Mediawiki : Issues when installing Visual Editor Extension with Parsoid

Tags: mediawiki, web-services, wysiwyg

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04 with mediawiki 1.27.0. 
I'm trying to install Parsoid and Visual Editor. I followed the [documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Parsoid/Setup) to the letter.
However, after finishing the installation, I have the first error message listed in the troubleshooting part of the documentation:

```
Error loading data from server: HTTP 500. Would you like to retry?
```

I tried all that is proposed to check the error.

1. curl is installed and works because the code below return a response.

   `curl -I -L http://wikirct/api.php`
2. I do not have any rewrite in my Apache configuration.
3. I think, but maybe I'm wrong, that my /etc/mediawiki/parsoid/settings.js is well set (see below).

parsoidConfig.setMwApi({ prefix: 'wiki', uri: 'http://wikirct/api.php', domain: 'wikirct' });

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Run the server<br>
You should be able to start the Parsoid web service from the parsoid directory.